# less.modifyVars not updating LESS variable

Tags: gruntjs, less

My project has a requirement to have a user-editable theme. Meaning the users should have the ability to change the different colors used in the application.

I've imported less.js (version 1.7.0) into my project and I've successfully called the less.modifyVars() function from my javascript but for some reason my less file isn't getting updated.

My stylesheet is dynamically compiled by grunt. This is the code in head of the HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/static/<%= grunt.config.get('pkg.name') %>.css"/>
```

And I've included the less.js script after that.

I then have this line of code just to modify a specific variable:

```
less.modifyVars({ '@mainColor': '#CCC' });
```

And I know it's being successfully called because I can see these in my browser console:

```
less: parsed http://localhost:3000/static/app.css successfully. less-1.7.0.js:7297
less: css for http://localhost:3000/static/app.css generated in 181ms less-1.7.0.js:7297
less: less has finished. css generated in 182ms
```

But the problem is when I inspect the supposedly updated CSS file, the different properties that use the variable @mainColor have not been updated with the new color.

Even when running the command in the browser console does not update anything in the CSS.

I've looked everywhere and I don't know what else to do. Any other ideas on what I could be doing wrong or what I can do to make this work?

Comment: Hmm, so you're compiling your less file server-side. But then include `less.js` script into you HTML and call `less.modifyVars` there, but that way the browser-side Less copy has nothing to do with your server-side build script and it is not involved in your server-side build chain at all and simply cannot affect your CSS. Or in other words, if you compile server-side you don't need and should not include `less.js` into your HTML because it will do nothing there (since HTML already gets the compiled CSS).

Comment: @seven-phases-max - Understood. But the reason why I want to use less.js is so I can incorporate the feature of customizable themes in my application. I need to be able to update less variables and reflect the changes to the page/s on runtime. Do you think this is possible considering that the application already initially compiles  the less file server-side?

Comment: The browser-side Less script can't modify pre-compiled CSS (simply because it is just a CSS) so you need either to initially link to the less file you want `modifyVars` to apply to (e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="yourstyles.less"/>`) or switch to it before the first `modifyVars` call.

Comment: @seven-phases-max - Thanks for the clarification and your help! I'll try to see if I can implement your advise.